# Error: Cannot find or load main class only when running outside of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mainclass

I've made a Java application which runs fine `inside` of eclipse
problem is, when I export it as a jar file and then attempt to run that jar file via windows cmd(current directory is the same as that of where I exported) with `java "2Dwars 2.0.jar"`

it says `Error: Could not find or load main class 2Dwars 2.0.jar`

I've searched google, and stackoverflow extensively, a lot of people are having similar problems, but none a similar solution.

my main class is as follows:

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame implements Controll.keyPressEvent
{

    static Render render;
    public init in;

    public MainClass()
    {
        new Options();

        setUndecorated(true);
        Options.setBoolean("Draw chunks", false);
        System.out.println("Test");

        add(new Render(new Controll()));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(895, 675);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("2D wars");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Adding render");


        System.out.println("Loaded Options.");
        System.out.println("added render");
        init in=new init();

        Controll.addListener(Controll.Key.ESC, this);

        new Sounds();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {           
        new MainClass();

    }

    @Override
    public void sendKeyPressEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==Controll.Key.ESC.getKeyCode())
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

System specs:

```
Windows vista 32 bit.
Jre 1.7 32 bit
JDk 5,6,7.
```

**EDIT** the issue can been resolved by exporting as a runnable and adding -jar to the command arguements, for some reason the jar had to be exported as a Runnable Jar to find the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run it as a jar file, you need the `-jar` option. Something like:

```
java -jar "2Dwars 2.0.jar"
```

(I'd suggest using a filename which doesn't have spaces in for simplicity's sake, too.)

Comment: Ty, this worked, but I was using the cmd console because exporting it as a runnable did not work, why is this?

Comment: to elaborate, when I export it as a runnable jar running it will not create a new process.

Comment: @user2104648: I don't understand what you mean. The export will just create a jar file, and running that jar file will definitely create a new process. It may not *work*, but that's a different matter.